# Can svn command line have two versions of diff -- one for visual and one for text?

Tags: svn

I can set up svn command line to diff using Meld, and using a Macbook Pro, I'd `ssh -X` to the Linux box so that the Linux box can do the Meld can send the window over to the Mac.

But sometimes, the file can be 2000 lines and I know there is just one or two lines of diff, and I just want a quick diff, or else the Meld will be quite slow, sending over the window and is quite slow to scroll to the line of diff.  Is there a way to invoke different diff tools?  Such as

```
svn diff        <-- the usual visual diff
svn textdiff    <-- doing just text diff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can customise `svn` commands, so the snarky answer is "use `git`" :P

Non-snarky answer is, you can set up a shell alias, or a shell script, that will invoke `svn diff` the way you want.

For example, if you use `bash`, you can put this into your startup file:

```
alias svntdiff="svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff"
```

and then use `svntdiff` vs. `svn diff` (which would presumably use Meld, as you configured it)

---

Another thing I can recommend is not passing Meld display through the network, but rather pass files. For this purpose, I often use the following script (`~/bin/sshm`):

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1
if [ -z "$HOST" ]; then
  echo Error: hostname not specified >&2
  exit 1
fi
mkdir -p /Volumes/$HOST
sshfs $HOST:/ -ofollow_symlinks /Volumes/$HOST
ssh $HOST
umount /Volumes/$HOST
```

You will need to install `sshfs` (`brew install sshfs`). Given that, now you can `sshm` into your linuxbox, but access all of your files through `/Volumes/linuxbox`. Then just run Meld locally, pointing at the mounted remote files. (or rather `mvimdiff`, in my case). The same thing also allows me to edit stuff on the remote server using MacVim, with all my configuration and plugins intact.

(You can also replace `sshfs $HOST:/ ...` with `sshfs $HOST: ...` to only mount your directory, not the whole file system.)

Comment: I think that's good solution... right now I am using ExpanDrive but I think `sshfs` does the same thing...  but I think if I do `svn` command on the Macbook, then it'd better be a specific file or folder, otherwise, `svn status` will take forever -- I waited for 1 minute and still no output (while on the Linux box, it takes 1 second).  That's because we install dependencies (library and modules) into our project, and there are 8000 files.

Comment: if possible, it should be really good to be able to invoke on the Mac, doing an `ssh`, and get back the file names to diff... and then invoke p4merge or araxis on the Mac to diff those files...

Comment: @動靜能量: Yup, that's what I meant. I use the console opened by my script for compilation, searching, stuff you do in a console and that need access to lots of files; and the sshfs mount for more targeted approach with Mac's GUI tools. I wouldn't run `ack` or `diff` on 8000 files through a mounted directory, either :p Also, my comment about `git` was not just a joke, if you have the ability to switch: as it is not a centralised VCS, when you diff, you diff against your local repository (which you keep in sync with your teammates), so it is always blindingly fast, and you can use all Mac's power.

Comment: yes, I think I have the issue that using svn, I can't commit any intermediate version until everything is done and perfect...